Getting mod_wsgi working on apache2 and Ubuntu 24.04
I recently stood up an Ubuntu Server 24.04 and installed apache2 (2.4) and have the basic web server working. I followed this tutorial (https://www.codearmo.com/blog/full-tutorial-deploying-python-dash-app-linux-serv) to get a Plotly Dash app to deploy so that I can get apache2 configured properly for WSGI. I am getting the 503 error that has a lot of questions and responses for it. My issue is getting the wsgi daemon and apache2 to communicate. My log file shows the issue:
[Thu Aug 22 14:56:13.229085 2024] [wsgi:alert] [pid 606:tid 127985749661568] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=606): Couldn't bind unix domain socket '/etc/apache2/logs/wsgi.606.0.1.sock'.

The /etc/apache2/logs/wsgi.606.0.1.sock path does not exist, which I am sure is the problem, but I cannot determine where this path is being set. It is not in any of the apache2.conf, 000-default.conf, wsgi.load, app.py, or app.wsgi files. Can anyone tell me where it is set, and what it should be pointing to? It seems like the socket file should be in /run/wsgi but no such file exists there, even if I knew where to change the reference.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks...Rob
